SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in Gitlab CI when I run my container as a service
To run end-to-end-tests with Playwright in the Gitlab CI, I build the required docker containers of my app in a previous job:
In the e2e-job, I use the containers as services:
e2e_tests:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH)
  stage:
    e2e_test
  needs:
    - build_api_dev
    - build_frontend_dev
  image:
    name: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.47.2-noble
  services:
    - name: mysql:8.0.32
      alias: database
    - name: schickling/mailcatcher
      alias: mailcatcher
    - name: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:api-dev-$CI_COMMIT_SHA
      alias: api
    - name: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:api-nginx-dev-$CI_COMMIT_SHA
      alias: nginx
    - name: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:frontend-dev-$CI_COMMIT_SHA
      alias: frontend
  variables:
    MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME: symfony
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_USER: symfony
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: symfony
    MYSQL_DATABASE: symfony_test
    DB_HOST: localhost
    DB_USER: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    DB_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    DB_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
    FRONTEND_URL: http://localhost:3000
    REACT_APP_PUBLIC_API_URL: http://localhost
  script:
    - mysql -h database -u root -proot <<< "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';"
    - mysql -h database -u root -proot symfony < db/dump-latest.sql
    - cd e2e
    - npm install
    - npm run test
  artifacts:
    name: "e2e-tests Report $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE"
    paths:
      - e2e/playwright-report/
    expire_in: 1 week

The database connection can not be established, I see the following error:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

When I run the container locally (in docker-compose) it works with the same database image.
Is there any special configuration required?

The MySQL server is not running or cannot be connected. Probably the Docker image does not start or the port is not passed to the external network.

The basics are known.
